# Snort: Reporting packet numbers

Tags: snort

I am making use of snort to match packets in pcap file against a set of rules. I want to log the results. I looked at the log file produced at var/log/snort but I want to know that **which packet numbers** corresponding to the original wireshark pcap file have reported matches. Which command will do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *test* logger. When running from the command line, add the option '-A test'.  The alert's output will have the format

(packet_number)  (gid)  (sid)  (rev).

packet_number corresponds to the pcap's packet number.  You can use the other three pieces of information to determine the rule which was triggered.